# mysqli_num_rows return 0 always

Tags: php, mysql

here am trying to get username and password from the database and if their result is found then redirect to some page but mysqli_num_rows returns 0 always i dunno why `

```
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {


    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $run  = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($run) == 1) {
        header("location: login.php");

    }}?>
```

`
[image: Here is my DB tables and columns]

Comment: add this line: `mysqli_error($con)` end of the code and see what's the error

Comment: No error i already tried it

Comment: try using raw data without passing variable

Comment: something like this: `SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE username = 'admin' AND password = 'admin'`

Comment: "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE username = 'admin' AND password = 'admin'"  check whether you get a correct value

Comment: no working as well

Comment: when i try this:  $query = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";  it did not work but when i try this  $query = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE username = '$username'"; it works fine

Comment: @HimanshuRahi then your password is wrong. Try printing it out before executing the query.

Comment: LOL i found the solution basically my db name and table name is same so when i change table name then it is work perfectly

Comment: Try to use `trim` function to remove extra white space by mistake we type.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "ornament";   // My local DB Name

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

            $username = "test";   // $_POST["username"] value
            $password = "test";     // $_POST["password"] value
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ornament` WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

             if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
                   echo "correct";

                } else {
                    echo "wrong";
                }



        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?> 

        </body>
        </html>
```

OUTPUT:

```
     correct
```

I have a  database name and table name are same, But for me it's working fine.

**NOTE: Please check the whether you are using correct password while getting from POST.**

Any how you got a solution,  Have a great day

Thanks

Muthu